# bash : assign vertical multi line output to a variable and get element summary

Tags: bash

i have output from dmidecode command:

```
Size: 32 GB Form Factor: DIMM Set: 3 Locator: A1
Size: 16 GB Form Factor: DIMM Set: 3 Locator: A2
Size: 32 GB Form Factor: DIMM Set: 3 Locator: B3
Size: 16 GB Form Factor: DIMM Set: 3 Locator: B4
```

i need to iterate over the array and if line contains A* i.e A1 or A2

i  need to take the size from that line  (32)  and add it to the next line that contails A
 i.e 32+16

i need to do the same for B3/4

what i came so far is:

```
IFS='--' read -r -a array <<< $(echo "$DIMM_SIZE_LOCATION")
for element in "${array[@]}";do
        #memory channels belongs cpu socket i.e A1 A2 ..
        SOCKET_CHANNELS=$(echo  "$element"|awk -F":" '{print $5}')
        #size if indevidual dimm
        DIMM_SIZE=$(echo  "$element"|awk -F":" '{print $2}'|grep -v "Error Information Handle"|egrep -o "[0-9]{1,6}")

        if [[ $element = *$SOCKET_CHANNELS* ]];then
                echo $DIMM_SIZE| paste -sd+ | bc
        fi
done
```

but i am not getting the expected results

Can you please suggest  a code that will do the job?

Comment: `<<<$(echo "...")` is a really inefficient way of writing `<<<"..."`. ("inefficient" in a runtime-performance sense, not just a wasted-characters sense).

Comment: ...similarly, `awk | grep | grep` can *always* be replaced with a better awk statement; awk's functionality is a strict superset of grep's.

Comment: ...and btw, `IFS='--'` is *exactly* the same as `IFS=-`. The characters in `IFS` form an unordered set; it's not an exact string to split on.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[substr($NF,1,1)]+=$2} 
    END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file

A 48
B 48
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed and awk, assuming text is sorted and contained in test.txt file

```
sed -re 's/Size: ([0-9]+).* Locator: ([AB][0-9])/\1 \2/' test.txt \
| gawk '
  {
    if($2 ~ /A[0-9]/) {
      asum+=$1
    } else if($2 ~ /B[0-9]/) {
      bsum+=$1
    }
  }
  END { print "asum=" asum, "bsum=" bsum }
'
```

properly emits:

```
asum=48 bsum=48
```

---

The whitespace is for readability; if compactness were a more important goal, it could instead be written on one line, as in:

```
sed -re 's/Size: ([0-9]+).* Locator: ([AB][0-9])/\1 \2/' test.txt  | gawk '{ if($2 ~ /A[0-9]/){ asum+=$1 }else if($2 ~ /B[0-9]/) { bsum+=$1 }} END{ print "asum=" asum, "bsum=" bsum}'
```